# How do I Save[] definitions associated to a symbol in Mathematica without saving subsidiary definitions?

Tags: save, wolfram-mathematica

The built-in Mathematica command [`Save[file, symbol]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Save.html) uses [`FullDefinition[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullDefinition.html) to look up the definition `symbol` and all of the subsidiary definitions.

For example, the commands

```
a:=b
c:=2a+b
Save[ToFileName[NotebookDirectory[],"test.dat"],c]
```

produces the file test.dat containing

```
c := 2*a + b
a := b
```

I have a program with a lot of prettifying [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MakeBoxes.html) type definitions that I do **not** want to be saved when I Save[] the many separate results.

In terms of the simple example above, I do not want the `a := b` definition saved to the file.  Does anyone know a neat way to make this happen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the documentation, `Save` uses `FullDefinition` while what you want is for it to use `Definition`. Using a `Block` we can override the global definition of any symbol, and in particular replace `FullDefinition` with `Definition` while running `Save`:

```
Block[{FullDefinition},
  FullDefinition = Definition;
  Save[filename, c]
  ];
FilePrint[filename]
DeleteFile[filename]
```

The magic works:

```
c := 2*a + b
```

EDIT. Wrapping things up with the right attributes:

```
SetAttributes[truncatedSave, HoldRest]
truncatedSave[filename_, args__] := Block[{FullDefinition},
   FullDefinition = Definition;
   Save[filename, args]];
```

Comment: That is a clever bit of magic! I never use `Block[]` as much as I should... I was trying to construct something similar to your `truncatedSave` using `Put` but was failing with premature evaluation of arguments despite using `HoldRest`.

Comment: @Simon: Yes, even though I have spend a lot of time trying to grok the distinction between Module, Block and With, I still find it confusing :)

Comment: With[]: declared variables are const.  Block[]: synonyms in the declared variables and the closure are the same.  Module[]: synonyms in the declared variables and the closure are unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
DumpSave["test1", c]
```

Does that.

Sample code:

```
a := b;
c := 2 a + b;
DumpSave["test1", c];
Clear[a, c];
<< test1
?a
?c
```

Out

```
_____________________
Global`a
_____________________
Global`c
c:=2 a+b
```

Comment: `DumpSave[]` uses a non-portable binary format - not the same clear text that `Save[]` produces. But you are right, `DumpSave` does not follow the dependencies of what it saves.

Comment: @Simon The manual states "Files written by DumpSave can only be read on the same type of computer system on which they were written." I wonder what is a *type* of computer system ... Same OS? Same processor family?

Comment: I imagine same processor family... but maybe also OS is important.

Answer (score 1):

## Warning - Warning - I don't know what I am doing

Just found this browsing the help system randomly.

Never before used  **RunThrough** ... anyway seems to do what you want.

```
Clear["Global`*"];  
a := b;  
c := 2 a + b;  
mathcommand =  StringReplace[First[$CommandLine], "MathKernel" -> "math"];
outputfile = "c:\\rtout";
RunThrough[mathcommand <> " -noprompt", Unevaluated[Put[Definition[c], "c:\\rtout"]]]
FilePrint[outputfile]
Clear[a, c];
<< "c:\\rtout"
DeleteFile[outputfile]
?c
```

Out

```
c := 2*a + b
_______________________________
Global`c
c:=2 a+b
```

**Edit.. Works on lists with a little Hold-Fu**

```
Clear["Global`*"];

(*Trick here *)
f[l_] := Definition @@ HoldPattern /@ Unevaluated@l;
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];

a := b;
c := 2 a + b;
d := 3 a + b;
mathcommand = StringReplace[First[$CommandLine], "MathKernel" -> "math"];
outputfile = "c:\\rtout";

RunThrough[mathcommand <> " -noprompt",Unevaluated[Put[Evaluate[f@{c, d}], "c:\\rtout"]]]

(* test *)

FilePrint[outputfile]
Clear[a, c, d];
<< "c:\\rtout"
DeleteFile[outputfile]  
?c  
?d
```

Comment: I did think of using `Put` but doing it with `RunThrough` seems a little round about. Using `Put[Definition[c],...]` for a single symbol works fine, but I had trouble getting it to work like `Save[]` does on a list of symbols.